# I want to format an array of integers. How do I send the array so that each verb receives a different element of the array?

Tags: go

I have a variable array of integers that I would like to format into a string.  When I pass the array, it is placed into the first format verb and the rest are listed as missing.  For example, I pass [10, 100, 250, 99] and a format of "%02d-%04d-%04d-%02d".  I want it to return "10-0100-0250-99".  What is the correct way to do this in go?

```golang
package main

include (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    nums := []int{10,100,250,99}
    format := "%02d-%04d-%04d-%02d\n"

    fmt.Printf(format, 10, 100, 250, 99)
    fmt.Printf(format, nums)
}
```

[10 100 250 99]-%!d(MISSING)-%!d(MISSING)-%!d(MISSING)   (Wrong)
10-0100-0250-99  (correct)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need to pass in the elements individually:

```
nums := []int{10,100,250,99}
format := "%02d-%04d-%04d-%02d\n"
fmt.Printf(format, nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3])
```

Or use the correct type for the `fmt.Printf` argument, which is `[]interface{}`:

```
nums := []interface{}{10,100,250,99}
format := "%02d-%04d-%04d-%02d\n"
fmt.Printf(format, nums...)
```

Comment: The first option works, however, I'm not always going to have 4 elements.  The second option (using `[]interface{}`) produces the same incorrect result.  Until I find a long term result, I can use a `switch` statement on the length of the array.  It should always be between 4 and 8 elements (until I hardcode that).

Comment: @MichaelLewis: I'm not sure what you mean, they produce identical results. You do of course have to switch over the length to match the format string. https://play.golang.org/p/viR1hTazJlH